# Pcie x16 slot 2 broken?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

So basicallly, I got a brand new px8z77-pro motherboard. All the pcie slots work appart from slot 2. Im trying to run Sli with my two gtx 680 and due to this problem, I am not able to.

My power supply is a corsair hx1050 and I'm running Windows 8 with a core i7 3700k. I tried to swap them around and the GPUs both work when they are not inserted in the pcie slot 2.

After reading lots of forums on the internet, I tried various solutions. One, which was of unsinstalling all of the nvidia drivers, clear the CMOS and reinstall the driver. That worked until I restarted the pc, then the problem came back again.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Does slot 2 work if it you run with a single GPU plugged into it, or only when you try to SLI?

Comment: @Ash both, it doesnt recognize any video cards that are inserted in it. All of the others work apart for the 2nd pcie

Comment: There's always the possibility that it's faulty. If the suggestions below don't work, you may need to get a replacement under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear but I will attempt to answer anyway

When you say the card in the second slot doesn't work - does the fan spin up, lights come on, etc? Are you expecting it to output a signal when connected to a monitor? AFAIK only the primary card will output a signal by default and you will need to configure this in software.

If you specify this information, others will be able to provide better answers.

---

1. Ensure that you have installed the SLI bridge.
2. Check that the second slot is enabled in the BIOS. Specifically, have a look at **NB PCIe Configuration** under the **Advanced** tab.
3. *Excerpt from the [PX8Z77 manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1155/P8Z77-V_DELUXE/E7163_P8Z77-V_Deluxe.pdf)*: From the NVIDIA Control Panel window, select **Set SLI Configuration**. Click
   **Enable SLI** and set the display for viewing SLI rendered content. When done, click
   Apply

Comment: yes, the fan works and all but the card isnt displayed under device manager and in the bios under the pcie page

Comment: im not sure where to go in the bios. Because its a uefi bios.

Comment: @AlessandroMiotto What's so special about a UEFI BIOS? Do you mean it is in "EZ Mode"? Press F7 in the BIOS to enter advanced mode.

Comment: @bhilliam oh sorry thought u were talking about normal bios. in nb pcie configuration, u cant do a lot of stuff.... just change "gen". But on pcie 2 its says disabled/empty even if my card is inserted

Comment: @AlessandroMiotto, As a sanity check before returning the motherboard, try loading the BIOS optimised defaults (F5)

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the card to slot number orientation for install per the manual.

If the cards are in the correct slots, you may be wise to return/exchange if you are still within that time span. Defects are possible and you may not want to invest too much time on it.

[image: slots]
[image: pci slots]